# JSON to JSON LD with minimal changes to the original JSON (all changes in JSON-LD context)

Tags: json, rdf, json-ld

**TL;DR**

If I have a JSON document like

```
{
  "policyid": "http://example.com/policy:0099",
  "policytype": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/Set" 
}
```

and I want have a JSON-LD document similar to

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "policytype": { "@id": "rdf:type",  "@type": "@id" }
   }
   "@id" : "http://example.com/policy:0099",
   "policytype": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/Set"
}
```

Is it possible to not change the name/vale pair { "policyid": "http://example.com/policy:0099" } to { "@id" : "http://example.com/policy:0099" } but rather say something in the context to say "policyid" -> "@id".

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "policytype": { "@id": "rdf:type",  "@type": "@id" },
    #### something here that says "policyid" -> "@id"
   }
   "policyid" : "http://example.com/policy:0099",
   "policytype": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/Set"
}
```

I was going through the spec example and couldn't find how to do that.

**More context**

Say if we have a model which has specification for RDF, and JSON Encoding, for example, [ODRL 2.1 Ontology](http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/) and [ODRL Version 2.1 JSON Encoding](https://www.w3.org/community/odrl/json/2-1/).

I want to start from JSON and generate JSON-LD by mapping JSON Encoding to the ODRL ontology.

```
{
  "policyid": "http://example.com/policy:0099",
  "policytype": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/Set",  
  "permissions": [{
     "target": "http://example.com/asset:9898",
     "action": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/reproduce"
  }]
}
```

The following is RDF model I want to convert this json to. 
(I will put the Turtle serialization to make it more readable).

```
@prefix odrl: <http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/> .

<http://example.com/policy:0099> a odrl:Set .
<http://example.com/policy:0099> odrl:permission _:perm0 .
_:perm0 odrl:action <http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/reproduce> .
_:perm0 odrl:target <http://example.com/asset:9898> .
```

I can do this with almost with minimal changes with a context as the following.

```
{
  "@context": { 
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "odrl": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/",
    "policytype": { "@id": "rdf:type",  "@type": "@id" },
    "permissions": { "@id": "odrl:permission",  "@type": "@id"},
     "target" : {"@id": "odrl:target",  "@type": "@id" },
     "action" : {"@id": "odrl:action",  "@type": "@id" }
  },
  "@id": "http://example.com/policy:0099",
  "policytype": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/Set",
  "permissions": [{ 
       "target": "http://example.com/asset:9898",
       "action": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/reproduce" }]
}
```

But if I want to keep the original JSON as it is, is there a way to say "policyid" -> "@id" in the context?

Many thanks!

Comment: perhaps you can use this library -> **https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js** the `jsonld.compact()` function seems to be what you are looking for ...

Comment: Thanks a lot David !! That's exactly the function I needed, I find jsonld.js quite useful. My doubt was about how to generate the context that the jsonld.compact() needs as an input in this particular case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to not change the name/vale pair { "policyid":
>   "http://example.com/policy:0099" } to { "@id" :
>   "http://example.com/policy:0099" } but rather say something in the
>   context to say "policyid" -> "@id".

Yes, you simply map policyid to `@id`. This is called [keyword aliasing in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#aliasing-keywords). So your example would look like this:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdf": "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#",
    "policyid": "@id",
    "policytype": { "@id": "rdf:type",  "@type": "@id" }
   },
   "policyid" : "http://example.com/policy:0099",
   "policytype": "http://www.w3.org/ns/odrl/2/Set"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @markus-lanthaler !! Somehow I missed keyword aliasing.